# How to compile a .so when it use a function in a executable?

Tags: android, gcc

When I compile `libb.so` and it depends on `liba.so`. I can run

```
g++ -la.
```

When `libb.so` uses a function from an executable `c`, what is the correct command?

```
g++ -lc
```

throws an error!!

I am trying to compile weston under android. The `gl_render.so` use the function from weston.

Comment: Please EDIT your post with in-depth information about your question. Try to be as descriptive as you can. That way, you will get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I want to compile 'libapi_simple.so' and it uses the function int module_add(int,int) of the executable file called 'test'.  the objs is compiled and the finnally cmd as following:

/code/phone/xmake/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-gnueabi-4.9-glibc-2.20/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libapi_simple.so -fPIC -fPIE -o /code/phone/out/platforms/phone.amlogic.eng.arm/target/obj/SHARED_LIBRARY/LINKED/libapi_simple.so /code/phone/out/platforms/phone.amlogic.eng.arm/target/obj/SHARED_LIBRARY/libapi_simple_intermediates/api.o /code/phone/out/platforms/phone.amlogic.eng.arm/target/obj/SHARED_LIBRARY/libapi_simple_intermediates/private.o    \
        -L/code/phone/out/platforms/phone.amlogic.eng.arm/target/obj/SHARED_LIBRARY/LINKED \
        -L/code/phone/out/platforms/phone.amlogic.eng.arm/target/obj/STATIC_LIBRARY \
        -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--build-id -L/code/phone/out/platforms/phone.amlogic.eng.arm/target/obj/SHARED_LIBRARY/LINKED -L/code/phone/out/platforms/phone.amlogic.eng.arm/target/rootfs/lib -L/code/phone/out/platforms/phone.amlogic.eng.arm/target/rootfs/usr/lib  \
        -Wl,-rpath=/usr/lib \
        -Wl,-rpath-link=/code/phone/out/platforms/phone.amlogic.eng.arm/target/obj/SHARED_LIBRARY/LINKED:/code/phone/out/platforms/phone.amlogic.eng.arm/target/rootfs/lib:/code/phone/out/platforms/phone.amlogic.eng.arm/target/rootfs/usr/lib
        /code/phone/out/platforms/phone.amlogic.eng.arm/target/obj/SHARED_LIBRARY/libapi_simple_intermediates/api.o: In function `get_api_tag()':
/code/phone/xmake/example/SHARED_LIBRARY_SIMPLE/api.cpp:9: undefined reference to`module_add(int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/code/phone/out/platforms/phone.amlogic.eng.arm/target/obj/SHARED_LIBRARY/LINKED/libapi_simple.so] Error 1

thanks

Comment: I wonder how to add 'test' in the cmd above to get the right result. if 'test' is a .so.  the problem is easy. but it's an executable item.  when I delete '-Wl,--no-undefined ' from the above, the compile ok but run failed